# Table calculation percentage difference within a field

Tags: tableau-api

I'm wondering how to add a new field that is a percentage difference between control and test (both in Group field)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can break out the test and control into their own measures.

Create a calculated field like:

```
if [group] = 'test' then [measure name] end
```

Repeat for control and all measures you have. Then you can create percent diff calcs as needed.

Comment: Hi Bernardo, thanks for the answer.  Is there any way to do this with some sort of [Column 1] / [Column 2] function rather than creating all of these new measures?

Comment: I'm not aware of a method like that.